# Comparable CompareTo For Dates not working

Tags: java

```
class Person implements  Comparable<Person>{
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy");
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private int age;
    private String dob;

    public Person(String name, String city, int age , String dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.age = age;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    // GETTERS/SETTERS

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return LocalDate.parse(p.getDob(),formatter).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(p.getDob(),formatter));
    }
}
```

Comment: For *sorting*, you should use a dedicated `Comparator` instead of implementing `Comparable`.

Comment: I dont want to use a Comparator

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy()` returns an `HashMap` without order. Collect your results in a `LinkedHashMap`, it will works I think.

Comment: @Dorian or as an alternative, use a `TreeMap` and properly implemented `equals` and `hashCode`...

Comment: @deHaar You're right, it's so much better !

Comment: "not working" is a very poor description of your problem.

Why It's not working? It fails? You get unexpected results? Which ones? What is the problem? How are you trying to compare? 

Please, read [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```
return LocalDate.parse(p.getDob(),formatter).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(p.getDob(),formatter));
```

Notice that you are comparing the DOB of `p` to the DOB of `p` here. This will always return `0`.

Try it like this:

```
return LocalDate.parse(this.getDob(),formatter).compareTo(LocalDate.parse(p.getDob(),formatter));
```

Also notice that you are comparing the full DOB's, including the day of the month, which does not match your requirement.

Comment: Thanks , but its not working ...